# Retrieve info from different collections based on different values - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: Collection1 and Collection2.

**Collection1**

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      link: {
        reference: "Collection2/abc123",
        display: "test"
      }
    }
```

**Collection2**

```
    {
      "id": "abc123",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": "efg456",
      "color": "blue"
    }
```

I am trying to get the contents by matching the link.reference value with the id of collection2.

If link.reference in collection1 and id in collection2 are the same, it is possible to get the reference with the following statement, but I am having trouble because the two values are different.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "collection2",
      localField: "link.reference",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "link.reference",  
    }
  },
])
```

Is it possible to implement these processes on mongodb using regular expressions or something?

Here is the [mongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qFxiDc5PSxv) for your reference.

I am new to mongoDB and would appreciate any help.

**desired result**

```
    [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "id": 1,
        "link": {
          "display": "test",
          "reference": [
            {
              "id": "abc123",
              "color": "red"
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Edit:2022/10/06**

With the help of some opinions (probably) solved.

Thanks.

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7vdv5nQBVt9)

Comment: you can `$split` on `/` and then `lookup` on substring at `index 1` .

Comment: Is the second collection dynamic? Eg can `Collection2` in `reference: "Collection2/abc123"` be any arbitrary collection?  If so then I don't think you can do this with MongoDB today.

Comment: @user20042973 Your comment means that in this example, if there is always a possibility that the field i want to refer to in link.reference is not collection2, it is impossible with the current mongo, right?  
If that's the case, and it's been discussed [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497), it sounds like you're right.